# How to display react-intl translation result for href?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, translation, jsx, react-intl

Is there any option to show contact number as `<a class="footer__links--contact--phone" href="tel:+44 1234 1234 12">` in react-int ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import messages from './messages';
    const ContactList = () => (
      <div className="footer__links--contact">
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(messages.phone)}</pre>
        <a className="footer__links--contact--phone" href={`tel:${messages.phone}`}>
          <FormattedMessage {...messages.phone} />
          <p className="footer__opening-hours">
            <FormattedMessage {...messages.availability} />
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
    export default ContactList;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide function as child component:

```
    <FormattedMessage {...messages.phone}>
       {phone => (
         <a className="footer__links--contact--phone" href={`tel:${phone}`}>
           {phone}
         </a>
       )}
     </FormattedMessage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this line correctly display the telephone?

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(messages.phone)}</pre>
```

If so then I believe you also have to apply the same logic to the href tag because of how the template string is converting the object to a string.

```
<a className="footer__links--contact--phone" href={`tel:${JSON.stringify(messages.phone)}`}>
```

Also be sure that you are using the correct format for the international prefix. The examples given in the [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/#bp-interaction-uri-schemes) docs use dashes instead of spaces so that may be something to consider as well.

Comment: Unfortunately `<pre>{JSON.stringify(messages.phone)}</pre>` giving result as `{"id":".Footer.link.phoneNumber","defaultMessage":"LINK"}`